# How can i return several fields directly in a WCF Response object, rather than wrapped in another object?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

How can i return a response from a WCF service with fields directly in the Response object, rather than wrapped in a Result object within the Response object?

I inherited and maintain WCF service that is working well. I've been asked to add a passthru method that does something, then routes a request to another existing service (maintained by someone else), then returns the result as-is. The part i'm trying to solve is that the existing service returns loose fields within their response object, but WCF appears to want me to return a single value (or values wrapped in an object).

How might i either:

- return multiple loose fields in the methodResponse object, or
- intercept the methodResponse and build/write it myself,
- something else to pass back the result as is?

Example, i want to return this (i.e. what's returned from the other service)

```
<soap:Body>
    <MethodResponse>
        <Value1>123</Value1>
        <Value2>abc</Value2>
        <Value3>http://123.com</Value3>
        <Value4>Success</Value4>
    </MethodResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

instead of this

```
<soap:Body>
    <MethodResponse>
        <MethodResult>
            <Value1>123</Value1>
            <Value2>abc</Value2>
            <Value3>http://123.com</Value3>
            <Value4>Success</Value4>
        </MethodResult>
    </MethodResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer. If the problem is not solved, please let me know.

Comment: Ding, i am unable to get this to work. There are other, existing, methods that i don't have [MessageContract] attributes, so i think that's possibly causing my problem (ServiceActivationException). So this isn't working for me. Is this an all-or-nothing situation where i'd have to do the same for all methods?

Answer (score 1):

If the MessageContractAttribute is not used in the service operation signature, WCF will create a wrapper element to save the parameters in the SOAP body. This is the default WCF behavior.

**The solution is to use [MessageContract] on the object.**

Here is my demo:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MethodResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string value2 { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string value3 { get; set; }
}
```

The above class is the class returned by the server.

[image]

This is the message received by the client.

For more information about MessageContract,Please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**This is my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static ConsoleApp65.soap;

namespace ConsoleApp65
{
    [MessageContract]
    public class MethodResponse
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string value1 { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string value2 { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string value3 { get; set; }
    }
  
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface Test
    {
        [OperationContract]
        MethodResponse Test();
    }
    public class TestService : Test
    {
        public MethodResponse Test()
        {
            MethodResponse data = new MethodResponse();
            data.value1 = "1";
            data.value2 = "2";
            data.value3 = "3";
            return data;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Step 1: Create a URI to serve as the base address.
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");

            // Step 2: Create a ServiceHost instance.
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), baseAddress);

            try
            {
                // Step 3: Add a service endpoint.
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Test), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

                // Step 4: Enable metadata exchange.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Step 5: Start the service.
                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");

                // Close the ServiceHost to stop the service.
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the service.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                selfHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ding, thank you but, hmm. Must be doing something wrong. I'm getting 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException. Is there anything different that needs to be done in the method itself, other than return an object of that type?

Comment: No need to perform other operations, you may need to update the service reference.